# Foreign Key table's fields null value not returning

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-8, hql

I have vendor table where manager is a foreign key. I'm trying to query for name of the manager, my query is like below.

```
`from TNewVendor t where t.archive=false and t.manager.name like "s"`.
```

With this query I'm getting only those records where manager is associated. If the manager field is null for any contract record then that record it will not fetch.

and if `from TNewVendor t where t.archive=false and t.manager.id like "s".`

with this query I'm getting all records whether manager is associated or not. But in this case I'm not able to filter manager field in the dashboard.

```
Pojo:--
public class TNewVendor{
     private String description;
     private String phone;
     private String fax;
     private TUser vendorManager;
}

public class TAVendorStringProperties{
     private Integer id;
     private TNewVendor vendor;
     private String s1;
     private String s2;
     private String s3;
     private String s4;
}
Query:-Select t.description,t.phone,t.fax,t.vendorManager.displayName from TNewVendor t left join TAVendorBooleanProperties t3 with t.id = t3.vendor.id left join TAVendorStringProperties t1 with t.id = t1.vendor.id WHERE t.vendorManager.displayName like ? AND t.archive = ? order by t.lastModifiedOn DESC
```

with this where condition-->t.vendorManager.displayName like ? With this condition I'm getting only those records where manager is associated. If the manager field is null for any vendor record then that record it will not fetch.

if I will use this Where condition-->t.vendorManager.id like ?
with this condition I'm getting all records whether manager is associated or not. But in this case I'm not able to filter manager field in the dashboard.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I can follow your post and I didn't see any real question. I _guess_ you're asking about why `t.manager.id like "s"` is returning contracts that don't have a manager assigned, right? Can you share the mapping and maybe some data examples?

Comment: I have edited the question can u check once.

Comment: You do realize that the `like` operator doesn't work on non-text properties, right? Since you didn't share `TUser` but the only other `id` you've shared is of type `Integer` I assume this is the same for the others too.